# Cant get int from Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

```
int sayd = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
int say = (int) Math.ceil(sayd);
Integer mapped = (Integer) GrandTheftCart.playerBounty.get(bounty);
int total = say + mapped;
```

So i'm checking the int like that, and whenever I run it I get a NullPointerException when i'm trying to retrieve the int.

**EDIT**

> ```
> public static HashMap<String, Integer> playerBounty = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
> ```

Comment: playerBounty is a map that is null or does not have any entries corresponding to bounty. What exactly happens is impossible to tell without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: what is the purpose of `int say = (int) Math.ceil(sayd);`? also please post a stacktrace

Comment: Sorry, let me edit the code so I can show how I define the map.

Comment: `int` added to a `null` `Integer` => NPE (as already stated below)

Comment: I defined it as a Integer as it was recommended somewhere that I should, I have tried already setting it as int mapped =  GrandTheftCart.playerBounty.get(bounty);

Comment: @Twipply That won't change anything. If no mapping exist the NPE will be thrown because the `Integer` will be unboxed to an int calling `.intValue()`. If you get `null` from the map, the NPE is thrown.

Comment: What do you expect for total when `mapped` is null? (`total = say`) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that NPE is thrown by this line:

`int total = say + mapped;`

It happens because `mapped` is `null`. Since arithmetic operations are defined for numeric primitives only java compiler performs a "magic" named autoboxing for you. It actually transforms your line to something like this:

`int total = say + mapped.intValue();`

It is pretty obvious that `mapped.intValue()` rises NPE if `mapped` is `null`.

Now the question is "why the value is null?" I think that the answer is "Because you have not put not-null value to to appropriate cell of your map."

Now, review your code and find where did you want to initialize the value and why it is not initialized. Then fix the bug. Good luck.

Comment: Big thankyou for this, made much more sense after I read over it a few times.

Answer (score 0):

it seems `bounty` is not contained in `playerBounty` map and it returns null to `mapped` variable, thus causing null pointer exception  in line `int total = say + mapped;`